# How to recompile invalid PLSQL packages that have been encrypted using Oracle 10g's Wrap utility?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

So I've taken an export (using Data Pump) from an Oracle 10g schema where all the PLSQL packages were encrypted using Oracle's **Wrap** utility. The problem is when I do an import of this into a new schema, all my packages are invalid, and trying a manual compile doesn't work.

```
SQL> ALTER PACKAGE mypackage compile;

Warning: Package altered with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE MYPACKAGE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
36/2     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "2"
```

So what's the solution to recompiling all these invalid packages?

Comment: was the imported database of a different release than the source db?

Comment: @tbone yes I believe it was a slightly different release, but I've been informed by a colleage that it also happens between the same release. In fact, apparently it's a known bug in Oracle. Still doesn't give me a solution though. :-(

Comment: I believe that the wrap is not downward compatible (ie, can't export from higher level and import into lower level release).  Thats why I asked anyway.  Also, I believe there as a known bug in 10g related to wrapped packages and data pump.  Do you have latest patches?

Comment: @tbone thanks for that. No, we don't have the latest patches on this particular system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears there is no "fix" for this issue, only workarounds, none of which are ideal.

1. Redo the export and import using the old exp and imp programs (instead of data pump)
2. If you have .SQL files containing the package definitions, you can manually compile them in SQL*Plus (might be thousands of files making this a big job).
3. You can patch the database (see Metalink article 460267.1)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the system `DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA` procedure to compile your schema objects. This procedure will determine the order in which to compile your objects and even handles circular dependencies. After a scripted schema build it's a good procedure to call for clean up.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA('MYSCHEMA');
END;
/
```

I'd be curious to know how well it handles wrapped objects.

Comment: @BrianFenton: Thanks for the feedback, that's good to know. I was curious if it would handle this problem.